# Hover Tips in VS Code are Not Appearing, C#, API

Tags: c#, .net, api, hover

I started a DatingApp project. I used dotnet and created project with many files. I installed a few extensions in VS Code: C# and C# Extensions.

My problem is that when I hover over elements of code, I don't see any tips; however, I see that my instructor in his video has many tips hovering over words he selects and so on.

I believe I don't get this issue when I am in Java Script files.

Does anyone not what settings I might need?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, come the top of the problem with mouse then push alt + enter buttons.